# передать строку запроса в PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Я только начал изучать php,html, js!
есть php -->

```
$host='10.20.30.40';
$user='root';
$password='pass';
$database='db';

$conDB = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
$conDB->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
if (!$conDB) {
    die('Не могу подключиться!');
}
if ($conDB) {
    $query=$_POST['string_query'];//string_query сформирована js
    $result = mysqli_query($conDB, $query);
    $result= mysqli_fetch_all($result);
}
```

Возможно ли передать сюда строку запроса, сформированную на стороне клиента джаваскриптом,и получить ответ?

```
let string_query="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` > '5' AND `name` = 'Nik'";
```

//эта строка сформирована js//

п.с. создать универсальный пхп для запросов к разным таблицам с разными условиями! Ответом получать всегда массив!
**Спасибо!**

Comment: ну так в чем проблема то? что-то не работает? надо отдать JSON обратно на клиента еще на стороне пхп (header content-type, echo json_encode).

Comment: Да проблема в том, что я полный 0. И чтобы мне понять как это реализовать мне нужен пример кода с пояснениями! Во всех учебниках и видеоуроках описание приводит к тому, что при пост-запросе указывается пхп в котором у же прописана строка запроса на выборку/удаление/добавление... А я пытаюсь сделать универсальный пхп который будет и выбирать, и удалять, и добавлять, и обновлять в разных таблицах базы

Comment: ajax-запрос есть у тебя? где? Также не удивляйся когда кто-нибудь в обход твоего фронта передаст запрос `DROP table` \ `DROP database`.

Comment: let string_query="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` > '5' AND `name` = 'Nik'";
 $.ajax({
  url: "connect.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data:{'string_query': string_query},
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data){
   var priz = JSON.parse(data);
  }
 }); //что-то типа этого. А на счет DROP - не переживаю - я же только начал изучать...

Comment: Ну и проблема тогда в чем? `$_POST['string_query']` есть, запрос выполняется, остается отдать джсон с результатом `echo json_encode()`. Если что-то идет не так - то надо открыть консоль разработчика в браузере и смотреть что приходит в результате запроса.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду экспериментировать!